# Select Menu, go to url on select with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onselect

I have the following html:

**HTML markup**

```
<ul id="test">
   <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

And some JS code:

**JQuery/JavaScript Code**

```
$('ul#test').each(function()
{
   var select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
   $('>li a', this).each(function()
   { 
 option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html());
   });
});
```

This code produces a select dropdown menu, exactly what I want, but my question is how do I go to the url on select? So if I click yahoo, it brings me to yahoo.com?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why mixing native js and jQuery that way? use $('<select/>') to create a new DOM element.

Comment: The auto-`<select>` “jump menu” is a discredited navigational tool; it has serious usability and accessibility problems. Please don't use this. How about just making the `<ul>` itself a pop-up element instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('ul#test').each(function()
{
   var select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
   $('>li a', this).each(function()
   { 
 option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html());
   });
   select.change(function(){
    //alert('url = ' + this.value );
    window.location.href = this.value;
  })
});
```

tested working [demo](http://jsbin.com/ukaco3/2) on major browsers.

Comment: This worked perfectly! One question though, if I were linking to my own site, is there any way to have jquery recognize which page I just linked to and make that one the default option in the select menu?

Comment: @Sean, can you explain further?

Comment: @Reigel Sure, look this for an example: http://pastebin.com/VUczwRpF If each page has the jquery url select is there any way to make it so if I click on the "cats" page to have cats show up as the default option in the jquery select menu when it takes me to the cats page? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$('ul#test').each(function()
{
   // also give the select an id
   var select = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('id', 'myselect').insertBefore($(this).hide());

   $('>li a', this).each(function()
   { 
     option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html());
   });
});
```

Now for redirecting....

```
$(function(){
  $('#myselect').live('change', function(){
    document.location.href = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

The **[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method used because your select box is created dynamically in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect in firefox and opera, but not ie 6,7 or chrome?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
 $('ul#test').each(function()
    {
       var select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
       $('>li a', this).each(function()
       { 
     option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html());
     option.click(function(){window.location = $(this).val())});
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! it wors again in frefox, but not in ie 6/7?

Answer (score 1):

add a change event to the creation of the select, and send user to the selected value.

```
var select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function(){
  document.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="dest" class="selec" onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
```

Comment: simple and useful but for select>option only :)