# using dropdown menu in html page

Tags: html

I am using the drop down in webpage and also the submit button to submit the selected value of the drop down.but i don't want to use the submit button. when i select the value from drop down it should re direct the page without using the submit button. can anyone post the code... i was using select and option tag.

Comment: Please add your code to your question or atleast a link to your website

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680465/select-menu-go-to-url-on-select-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

See [Navigational pulldown menus in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html) for a comprehensive guide, but in a nutshell:

- Bind an onchange JavaScript event handler to the select element that calls the forms `submit()` method
- Don't do this, it is a horrible UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript to perform this operation.

For example, in jQuery, you could do something similar to:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDropDownId').change(function() {
        $('#formId').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery:**

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val())
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can do this with Javascript. Change your select box to look like this.

```
<select name="NAME" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: Make sure you add a submit button as well that you remove with JavaScript, so that if a user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, they can still use the navigation.